# VPN routing issue with PulseSecure

Tags: routing, vpn

I have a Windows PC (192.168.10.99) in the local network 192.168.10.0/24.

Default gateway in this network (192.168.10.1) has a VPN connection to the remote network 10.8.0.0/16 (**RN1**) that can be accessed from the PC. Also I can create a personal PulseSecure VPN connection on the PC to another remote network with the similar pool of IP-addresses: 10.0.0.0/8 (**RN2**). At the time of connection PulseSecure creates routes with a metric = 1, include a route for **RN2**, so **RN1** becomes unavailable on the PC.

How to make the route for 10.8.0.0/16 lead only to **RN1**, not to **RN2**?

I tried adding a new route (10.8.0.0/16) for the desired interface (192.168.10.99) with metric = 1, but it gets a metric = 26

I can’t influence the settings of VPN connections or change the settings of subnets, only my PC is available to me.

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.10.1    192.168.10.99     25
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link      10.200.10.51      1
        10.20.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      10.200.10.51      1
        10.30.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      10.200.10.51      1
        10.40.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      10.200.10.51      1
     10.200.10.51  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.200.10.51    256
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.10.99    281
    192.168.10.99  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.10.99    281
   192.168.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.10.99    281
 <PulseSecure IP>  255.255.255.255    192.168.10.1     192.168.10.99     25
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.10.99    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.200.10.51    256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.10.99    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.200.10.51    256
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: It also turned out that PulseSecure changes DNS addresses on the local network adapter when connected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your post so I can earn some points finally :)

I'm doing this right today about PulseSecure stuff and why you could not do it yet after Zac67 almost correct answer is becuase there was some missing piece yet.

Well, interfaces are having their seed metric which adds up with that of routes to yield a final value. So you must artificially change Pulse VPN link metric to some other value than 0! to eventually make your specific route win in this setup.

Here it's all to understand, won't paste it here as not my content, enjoy!
https://kb.zensoft.hu/route-different-traffic-thru-different-network-interfaces-in-windows/

Thanks for eventual vote up.
Have a nice day
Peter

Comment: Thanks! I've changed interface metric by the following command: _netsh interface ipv4 set interface "Local Area Connection* 10" metric=27_ and it works well!

Comment: Glad I've helped! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a specific route to 10.8.0.0/16 via your default gateway. Currently, the default isn't used because of the more specific 10.0.0.0/8 route.

The routing logic selects the most specific route (longest prefix) for each destination. /8 is longer than the /0 default, so 10.8.x.y would use the former.

Comment: I tried to add a route by the following command: route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.10.1 IF <local network interface number> METRIC 1, but did not succeed

Comment: "did not succeed" - was the route successfully added but doesn't work? What does the routing table look like? What does tracert say?